# ¿Forma de nombrar una clase de test en Java?

Tags: java, junit, junit-4

Estoy haciendo un curso de Testing (Están utilizando Junit4 )en java, y menciona que la clase de Test debería terminar en **should** para que el Test diga que es lo que debería hacer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que siguiendo esa lógica el Test tenga el siguiente nombre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes la clase la tenía nombrada **FizzBuzzShould** pero al momento de hacer build al proyecto, no me reconocía los 30 Test que tenía en esa clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías poner las imagenes como texto, [formateado](/help/formatting) por favor? Aquí se enumeran los motivos por los cuales no es buena idea usar capturas de texto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Answer (score 0):

El Nombre no influye al correr el test, te invito a que revises los parametros al correr el junit y ver que el tag @ esta correcto.
Tambien observa que el compilador no te de ningun error al hacer el build.